# Spring WebFlux Nested RoutingFunction

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have the following routes:

```
/claims
/claims/body
/claims/approvals
/claims/{id}
/claims/{id}/bills
```

To define them using `RouterFunction` I did:

```
RouterFunctions.nest(
        RequestPredicates.path("/claims"),
        RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.GET("/approvals"), handler1::handleRequest)
                .andRoute(RequestPredicates.GET("/body"), handler2::handleRequest)
                .andRoute(RequestPredicates.GET("/{id}"), handler3::handleRequest)
                .andNest(
                        RequestPredicates.path("/{id}"),
                        RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.GET("/bills"), handler4::handleRequest)
                )
)
.andRoute(RequestPredicates.method(HttpMethod.GET), handler5::handleRequest)
.andRoute(RequestPredicates.method(HttpMethod.POST).and(RequestPredicates.accept(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)), handler6::handleRequest);
```

This configuration is working. But, I have to define `RequestPredicate` for `/{id}` twice. Is it the right way of writing the `RouterFunction`?

Comment: Why not just write `RequestPredicates.GET("/{id}/bills")` instead of using using the andNest? Feels overkill here.

Comment: @M.Deinum, thanks for the comment. I want to accept it as the answer. Could you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just write `RequestPredicates.GET("/{id}/bills")` as the predicate instead of using `andNest`. The nesting feels a bit like an overkill here.